# Display an XML attribute value only on the first encounter with XSL

Tags: xslt

I have this XML fragment:

```
   <svrl:active-pattern document="file:/D:/3.4Workspace/antSchematronTest/xml/CDA.xml"
                        id="p-2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.31-warning"
                        name="Result observation - warning validation phase"/>
   <svrl:fired-rule context="*[cda:templateId/@root=&#34;2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.31&#34;]"/>
   <svrl:failed-assert test="cda:code[@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.1' or @codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96' ]"
                       location="/*[local-name()='ClinicalDocument']/*[local-name()='component']/*[local-name()='structuredBody']/*[local-name()='component'][4]/*[local-name()='section']/*[local-name()='entry'][1]/*[local-name()='organizer']/*[local-name()='component'][1]/*[local-name()='observation']">
      <svrl:text>The value for "Observation / code" in a result observation SHOULD be selected from LOINC (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.1) or SNOMED CT (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.96).</svrl:text>
   </svrl:failed-assert>
   <svrl:failed-assert test="count(cda:effectiveTime)=1"
                       location="/*[local-name()='ClinicalDocument']/*[local-name()='component']/*[local-name()='structuredBody']/*[local-name()='component'][4]/*[local-name()='section']/*[local-name()='entry'][1]/*[local-name()='organizer']/*[local-name()='component'][1]/*[local-name()='observation']">
      <svrl:text>A result observation SHOULD contain exactly one Observation / effectiveTime, which represents the biologically relevant time (e.g. time the specimen was obtained from the patient).</svrl:text>
   </svrl:failed-assert>
   <svrl:failed-assert test="cda:referenceRange"
                       location="/*[local-name()='ClinicalDocument']/*[local-name()='component']/*[local-name()='structuredBody']/*[local-name()='component'][4]/*[local-name()='section']/*[local-name()='entry'][1]/*[local-name()='organizer']/*[local-name()='component'][1]/*[local-name()='observation']">
      <svrl:text>A result observation SHOULD contain one or more Observation / referenceRange to show the normal range of values for the observation result.</svrl:text>
   </svrl:failed-assert>
   <svrl:fired-rule context="*[cda:templateId/@root=&#34;2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.31&#34;]"/>
   <svrl:failed-assert test="cda:code[@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.1' or @codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96' ]"
                       location="/*[local-name()='ClinicalDocument']/*[local-name()='component']/*[local-name()='structuredBody']/*[local-name()='component'][4]/*[local-name()='section']/*[local-name()='entry'][1]/*[local-name()='organizer']/*[local-name()='component'][2]/*[local-name()='observation']">
      <svrl:text>The value for "Observation / code" in a result observation SHOULD be selected from LOINC (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.1) or SNOMED CT (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.96).</svrl:text>
   </svrl:failed-assert>
```

I'm applying this XSL template to the fragment:

```
<xsl:template name="svrl:failed-assert" match="svrl:failed-assert">
        <p><u>
                    <xsl:value-of select="(preceding-sibling::svrl:active-pattern)/@name[1]" />

        </u></p>    
        <table width="800">
           <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><font color="red"><xsl:value-of select="svrl:text" />
                    </font></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td width="50">Location:</td>
              <td width="750">
              <i>
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                     <xsl:with-param name="text">
                        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                           <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@location"/>
                           <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="&quot;*[local-name()='&quot;"/>
                           <xsl:with-param name="by" select="''"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                     </xsl:with-param>
                     <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="&quot;']&quot;"/>
                     <xsl:with-param name="by" select="''"/>
                  </xsl:call-template> 
              </i></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td width="50">Test:;</td>
              <td width="750"><i><xsl:value-of select="@test" /></i></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
</xsl:template>     
 <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text"
          select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

This is the output:

```
 Result observation - warning validation phase

The value for "Observation / code" in a result observation SHOULD be selected from LOINC (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.1) or SNOMED CT (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.96).
Location:   /ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component[4]/section/entry[1]/organizer/component[1]/observation
Test:;  cda:code[@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.1' or @codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96' ]
Result observation - warning validation phase

A result observation SHOULD contain exactly one Observation / effectiveTime, which represents the biologically relevant time (e.g. time the specimen was obtained from the patient).
Location:   /ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component[4]/section/entry[1]/organizer/component[1]/observation
Test:;  count(cda:effectiveTime)=1
Result observation - warning validation phase

A result observation SHOULD contain one or more Observation / referenceRange to show the normal range of values for the observation result.
Location:   /ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component[4]/section/entry[1]/organizer/component[1]/observation
Test:;  cda:referenceRange
Result observation - warning validation phase

The value for "Observation / code" in a result observation SHOULD be selected from LOINC (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.1) or SNOMED CT (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.96).
Location:   /ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component[4]/section/entry[1]/organizer/component[2]/observation
Test:;  cda:code[@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.1' or @codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96' ]
```

I want the `svrl:active-pattern@name-“Result observation - warning validation phase”` to display only once. For example:

```
   Result observation - warning validation phase

The value for "Observation / code" in a result observation SHOULD be selected from LOINC (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.1) or SNOMED CT (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.96).
Location:   /ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component[4]/section/entry[1]/organizer/component[1]/observation
Test:;  cda:code[@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.1' or @codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96' ]


A result observation SHOULD contain exactly one Observation / effectiveTime, which represents the biologically relevant time (e.g. time the specimen was obtained from the patient).
Location:   /ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component[4]/section/entry[1]/organizer/component[1]/observation
Test:;  count(cda:effectiveTime)=1


A result observation SHOULD contain one or more Observation / referenceRange to show the normal range of values for the observation result.
Location:   /ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component[4]/section/entry[1]/organizer/component[1]/observation
Test:;  cda:referenceRange


The value for "Observation / code" in a result observation SHOULD be selected from LOINC (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.1) or SNOMED CT (codeSystem 2.16.840.1.113883.6.96).
Location:   /ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component[4]/section/entry[1]/organizer/component[2]/observation
Test:;  cda:code[@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.1' or @codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96' ]


A result observation SHOULD contain one or more Observation / referenceRange to show the normal range of values for the observation result.
Location:   /ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component[4]/section/entry[1]/organizer/component[2]/observation
Test:;  cda:referenceRange
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What you are asking is not complicated, but it would help a lot if you simplifiy your code samples to the barest minimum to indicate exactly what the problem is. The call to "string-replace-all", for example, is not actually relevant to the problem in this case, and just takes up space in your XSLT. Also you should try and explain a bit more about you are trying to achieve, as at the moment it feels like playing 'spot the difference' with the exptected results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only want to output the paragraph for the "Result observation - warning validation phase" message for the first **svrl:failed-assert** element you find in your XML, but not for any of the others.

What you need to do is have a template to match the first such element, which can output the first paragraph, and then calls the named template **svrl:failed-assert** which will also match all the other elements too.

```
<xsl:template match="svrl:failed-assert[1]">
   <p>
      <u>
         <xsl:value-of select="(preceding-sibling::svrl:active-pattern)/@name[1]"/>
      </u>
   </p>
   <xsl:call-template name="svrl:failed-assert"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="svrl:failed-assert" name="svrl:failed-assert">
    <!-- Existing code here -->
```

Here is a simplified XSLT (without any find-and-replace code)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:svrl="oh:no" exclude-result-prefixes="svrl">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="svrl:failed-assert[1]">
      <p>
         <u>
            <xsl:value-of select="(preceding-sibling::svrl:active-pattern)/@name[1]"/>
         </u>
      </p>
      <xsl:call-template name="svrl:failed-assert"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="svrl:failed-assert" name="svrl:failed-assert">
      <table width="800">
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
               <font color="red">
                  <xsl:value-of select="svrl:text"/>
               </font>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="50">Test:</td>
            <td width="750">
               <i>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@test"/>
               </i>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following simplified XML:

```
<a xmlns:svrl="oh:no">
   <svrl:active-pattern name="Result observation - warning validation phase"/>
   <svrl:fired-rule context="Context 1"/>
   <svrl:failed-assert test="Test 1" location="Location 1">
      <svrl:text>Text 1</svrl:text>
   </svrl:failed-assert>
   <svrl:failed-assert test="Test 2" location="Location 2">
      <svrl:text>Text 2</svrl:text>
   </svrl:failed-assert>
   <svrl:fired-rule context="Context 2"/>
   <svrl:failed-assert test="Test 3" location="Location 3">
      <svrl:text>Text 3</svrl:text>
   </svrl:failed-assert>
</a>
```

The following HTML is output:

```
<p>
   <u>Result observation - warning validation phase</u>
</p>
<table width="800">
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
         <font color="red">Text 1</font>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">Test:</td>
      <td width="750">
         <i>Test 1</i>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table width="800">
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
         <font color="red">Text 2</font>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">Test:</td>
      <td width="750">
         <i>Test 2</i>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table width="800">
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
         <font color="red">Text 3</font>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="50">Test:</td>
      <td width="750">
         <i>Test 3</i>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you sir i really do not explain exactly what i want
example are as follows
[code]
[/code]